# Object.ReferenceEquals prints true for two different objects

Tags: c#

How is the below code is printing `true`?

```
string x = new string(new char[0]);
string y = new string(new char[0]);
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(x,y));
```

I expected this to print `False`, because I expected two separate objects to be constructed and then their references compared.

Comment: Because they're two equal objects... `string` overrides `Equals`. Why did you expect it to print `false`?

Comment: (Did you mean to call `object.ReferenceEquals` instead of `Equals`?)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes exactly, sorry i changed the code in experimenting :P

Comment: [What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-sharp-or-net)

Comment: The code is *exactly* the same :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter that question doesn't answer my queries?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well I post the link because this case is also mentioned there. IMO it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you check the update in the question? second code block?

Comment: @hvd+others: it's reopened so your comment is redudant. Kylo, please don't ask multiple questions in one, all the more if you've already accepted one. Ask another question

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok. will do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because special case is made for constructing empty strings from empty char arrays. The string constructor returns `string.Empty` for empty strings constructed in this way:

```
string x = new string(new char[0]);
string y = new string(new char[0]);
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)); // true
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(x, string.Empty)); // true
```

From the [reference source for string](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) (this is the constructor for a `char*` parameter):

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
private unsafe String CtorCharPtr(char *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == null)
        return String.Empty;

#if !FEATURE_PAL
    if (ptr < (char*)64000)
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeStringPtrNotAtom"));
#endif // FEATURE_PAL

    Contract.Assert(this == null, "this == null");        // this is the string constructor, we allocate it

    try {
        int count = wcslen(ptr);
        if (count == 0)
            return String.Empty;

        String result = FastAllocateString(count);
        fixed (char *dest = result)
            wstrcpy(dest, ptr, count);
        return result;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ptr", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_PartialWCHAR"));
    }
}
```

And also (this is the constructor for a `char[]` parameter):

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    private String CtorCharArray(char [] value)
    {
        if (value != null && value.Length != 0) {
            String result = FastAllocateString(value.Length);

            unsafe {
                fixed (char * dest = result, source = value) {
                    wstrcpy(dest, source, value.Length);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
```

Note the lines:

```
        if (count == 0)
            return String.Empty;
```

and

```
        else
            return String.Empty;
```

Comment: He uses the string contructor which normally returns a non-interned object.

Comment: does by using String.Intern, we can change the output?

Comment: This *isn't* due to string interning - not normal string interning. It's nothing to do with the compiler, either.

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct, I've removed that part of the answer.

Comment: Good find on the actual optimization! I am sorry Jon always beat us to it :)

Comment: Actually `String.Empty` [is not even interned](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/), at least not in some versions of the .NET runtime. It's not a constant but a read-only field, so another oddity.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks,( that is how it happen actually for string class.)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, you're right - I've removed any mention of interning.

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you check the update in the question?\

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I've rolled back that update, as it should never have been in the question, given that it's about a different situation.

Comment: @JonSkeet True, and it's then a duplicate question. I'll just remove my update here and link to a duplicate question in a comment here.

Comment: @KyloRen [Here's a sample question that would be a duplicate of your one about string interning.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779422/two-different-strings-are-the-same-object-instance)

Answer (score 5):

This is an undocumented (as far as I'm aware) optimization in the CLR. It's very odd, but yes: the `new` operator is returning the same reference from two calls.

It appears to be implemented in CoreCLR as well on Linux (and even on Mono).

The string constructor is the only example of this that I've seen, although as noted in comments you can provoke it with other constructor overloads.

I'm convinced it's an optimization in the CLR, as the IL is as you'd expect it - and moving the constructor call into a different method doesn't change things either:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declaring as object to avoid using the == overload in string
        object x = CreateString(new char[0]);
        object y = CreateString(new char[0]);
        object z = CreateString(new char[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(x == y); // True
        Console.WriteLine(x == z); // False        
    }

    static string CreateString(char[] c)
    {
        return new string(c);
    }
}
```

Now that the CLR is open source, we can find out where this is performed. It appears to be in [`object.cpp`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/object.cpp) - if you search for occurrences of `GetEmptyString` you'll see it used in various cases when a string of length 0 is being constructed.

Comment: why do you say optimization?

Comment: Because it doesn't need to calculate the new string, it now has become a constant @KyloRen

Comment: `string` is the only example I know of too, but it's not limited to that single constructor: `object.ReferenceEquals(new string(' ', 0), new string(new char[0]))` returns `true` as well.

Comment: Oh my, it is a in-code optimization. Cool you found it. I wonder how often that gets called :)

Comment: @JonSkeet can you explain the second code block ? Is it cause of string intern?

Comment: @KyloRen: Please stop changing the question. You should ask *one* question per post - the second code block is about something entirely different. I will roll back your update.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok. I'll post that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `object.Equals` first checks on reference equality, and then calls `Equals` on the first variable (`x`).

`string.Equals` checks against the actual value of a string (using the current culture settings, which may influence the comparison), not only the reference, so it returns `true` since both objects have the same value.

---

For your edit: it seems that the CLRr does some magic and tries to evaluate your `new string(char[0])`, so it can be interned. You can see the same behavior if you set `x` to `""`.

Comment: Note that this answer is now irrelevant as the question has changed.

Comment: It's *not* a compile-time check. The IL here is exactly as you'd expect it to be.

Comment: So it is the JIT'ter then? @JonSkeet

Comment: Either the JIT or whatever gets called when you call `new string(char[])`.

Comment: Found it now, in `object.cpp` - see my answer for a link.