# How to manufacture an empty string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have written a piece of optimized code that contains special cases for `null` and empty strings. I am now trying to write a unit test for this code. In order to do that, I need two empty (zero-length) string objects that are different objects. Like this:

```
string s1, s2;
Assert.IsTrue(s1.Length == 0 && s2.Length == 0);
Assert.IsTrue(!ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
```

It turns out that most .NET Framework APIs string are checking for an empty result. They are returning `string.Empty` in all those cases. For example, `"x".Remove(0, 1)` returns `string.Empty`.

How can I create fresh zero-length string objects?

Comment: Strings that are not created in runtime are interned. So, strings with the same value reference the same object in common string pool. Why do you need this?

Comment: If you check out the sources of the `String.Remove()`, you'll see that it returns `String.Empty`, yes. https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L2926

Comment: @dbc Same for `new string('X', 0);`  See [Object.ReferenceEquals prints true for two different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37068824/150605).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Obsolete method [String.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy)

```
string s1 = "";
string s2 = String.Copy("");
Assert.IsTrue(s1.Length == 0 && s2.Length == 0);
Assert.IsTrue(!ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works since some of the `string` methods are special-cased to return `string.Empty` when they can.  The documentation even says "because of changes in string interning in .NET Core 3.0, in some cases the `Copy` method will not create a new string but will simply return a reference to an existing interned string", yet this works for me on that version (perhaps because `string.IsInterned(string.Empty)` returns `false`).

Comment: This still exists in .NET Core 3.0 although there was talk on GitHub of removing it or making it just return it's input. I tested this on .NET Framework 4.8.

Answer (score 11):

There is no true 100% supported way of manufacturing a fresh zero-length string in .NET. *As an implementation detail*, existing string APIs may try to normalize zero-length return values to the instance `string.Empty`, but whether or not they do this consistently isn't something a developer should be relying on.

In particular, the other two answers have problems:

- The `string.Copy` solution even includes the caveat that the method is obsolete in .NET Core 3.0. The method is likely to be removed entirely from a future version of .NET Core, so any solution which relies on calling `string.Copy` is going to break when the application eventually moves on to the new version of the runtime.
- The `FastAllocateString` solution takes a dependency on an undocumented, internal API within the runtime. Internal APIs aren't guaranteed to stick around between versions. In fact, [we're planning major changes](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/98d47d5fc0f1b232869a9abd27729235fd7355b0/docs/design/features/StringDeduplication.md) in the way strings behave in the next version of .NET, and that work will almost certainly affect this internal API.

So, to your particular question as to whether there's a *reliable* way to manufacture a fresh zero-length string instance, the answer is no.

If you want to special-case zero-length strings in your code, the best solution would be to use the pattern `if (myString.Length == 0) { /* ... */ }`. The patterns `if (myString == string.Empty) { /* ... */ }` and `if (myString == "") { /* ... */ }` will also work, but their codegen won't be as optimized as the first proposal.

If you want to special-case null or empty strings, the best solution would be to use the existing `string.IsNullOrEmpty` API. The implementation of this method changes from [version](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/17b97365645da62cf8a49444d979f94a59bbb155/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L793) to [version](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/fddce702c2ff94c6ca05e401cfb0eb1944083767/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs#L434) to take advantage of whatever JIT optimizations are available at the time.

Source: I am one of the primary developers on the System.String class.

Comment: I have written a custom string interning solution to save memory. That code optimizes all empty strings to `string.Empty`. I'd like to test that. Now given how hard it is to produce an empty string I also could simply delete this optimization.

Comment: If memory is a concern for your application you should definitely check out the [string deduplication](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/98d47d5fc0f1b232869a9abd27729235fd7355b0/docs/design/features/StringDeduplication.md) feature that's being prototyped in .NET 5. The tl;dr of this feature is that during GC, equivalent strings will be collapsed to the same instance wherever possible, freeing up memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FastAllocateString`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,78a459e3adf6b1d6) method for that (it's being used internally in `String` and `StringBuilder` classes). Since it has `internal static` modifier, you should use reflection to invoke. But it returns two different empty strings in a memory

```cs
var fastAllocate = typeof(string).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(x => x.Name == "FastAllocateString");

string s1 = (string)fastAllocate.Invoke(null, new object[] { 0 });
string s2 = (string)fastAllocate.Invoke(null, new object[] { 0 });
var zeroLength = s1.Length == 0 && s2.Length == 0;
var notEqual = !ReferenceEquals(s1, s2);
```

Both checks returns `true` here